Conditionally changing elements of a numpy array using for loop
I have a two dimensional numpy array, and I'm wanting to change all of the 'male' values to 0 and all of the 'female' values to 1.
If I try to assign arr2D[row,element] to a specific value,
I get an error.
I tried using the code below, but instead of getting my hoped for
array of '[[0,0],[1,1]]' I got an error:

'IndexError: arrays used as indices must be an integer...'

I don't know how to determine the index of the element that I'm
looking at in my for loop.
import numpy as np

arr2D = np.array([['male',0],['female',1]])

for row in arr2D:
    for element in row:
        if element == 'male':
                        arr2D[row,element] = 0
        if element == 'female'
            arr2D[row,element] = 1
            
            
for row in arr2D:
    for element in row:
        print(element)


A : is missing in your code, and for proper display you'd put ``` lines around it.


I don't know how to determine the index of the element that I'm looking at in my for loop.

You can use enumerate:
    for index, element in enumerate(row):
        if element ==   'male': row[index] = 0
        if element == 'female': row[index] = 1

But you can also do without explicit loops using numpy.place:
np.place(arr2D, arr2D==  'male', 0)
np.place(arr2D, arr2D=='female', 1)

